# Assistance with part of a join

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm a college student and the database I'm working with is purely fictional but part of it requires me to make a query that is a join.

What I have are 3 tables each with part of the data but also needing to use two of those tables as conditions based off the main table. What I mean is I have an employee table, order table and customer table and the only thing any two of them have in common is the ID of either the employee or the customer is part of the order table.

Now what I am trying to do is create a join statement that will get certain information from the employee and customer tables and only those that both the employee and the customer are also on the same line in the order table. How should i make this type of conditional statement?

Any example using the same basic scenario will work I can use that to help me build my own query.

This is what I have right now:

```
SELECT [Customer/Vendor_Info_local].Name_of_customer,
       Employee_Info_local.Employee_Name
FROM Employee_Info_local,
     [Customer/Vendor_Info_local],
     Order_Information_local
WHERE (([Customer/Vendor_Info_local].[Customer/VendorID] =
           [Order_Information_local].[Cu‌​srtomer/VendorID])
       AND
       ([Employee_Info_local].[EmployeeID] = [Order_Information_local].[EmployeeID]));
```

I keep getting a type mismatch error when i try to use it and honestly not even sure what that means.

Comment: You should start by using explicit `join` syntax. Are they still teaching implicit joins in your college?

Comment: Isn't Access tricky when doing double explicit join?

Comment: that query was made via the query designer with the relationships of the three tables showing when i made it. No idea why a Join statement isn't in there anywhere.

Comment: "Data type mismatch" on one side of a join there is data that is incompatible with the other side of that join. E.g text attempting to join to dates. Look at the actual data in the columns you are trying to join by. If they are not of the same type you will get this type of problem.

Comment: Alrighty that helped a lot the data types in the order info table was as text for both the ID fields so changed that and this is the sql i have now  (see next comment)

Comment: SELECT [Customer/Vendor_Info_local].Name_of_customer, Employee_Info_local.Employee_Name, [Customer/Vendor_Info_local].[Customer/VendorID]
FROM [Customer/Vendor_Info_local] INNER JOIN (Employee_Info_local INNER JOIN Order_Information_local ON Employee_Info_local.EmployeeID = Order_Information_local.EmployeeID) ON [Customer/Vendor_Info_local].[Customer/VendorID] = Order_Information_local.[Cusrtomer/VendorID]
WHERE (([Customer/Vendor_Info_local].[Customer/VendorID]=[Order_Information_local].[Cusrtomer/VendorID]) AND ([Employee_Info_local].[EmployeeID]=[Order_Information_local].[EmployeeID]));

Comment: Ok got it now ty all for the tips and hints as always much appreciated